# pass parameters in crosstab query postgres

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

How to pass a parameter in `crosstab` query in `postgresql`.
Please refer the below function in postgresql

```
create function sp_nextfollowup_count_byweek(_from timestamp without time zone,_to timestamp without time zone)
returns table(userid integer,username character varying,day1 bigint,day2 bigint,day3 bigint,day4 bigint,day5 bigint,day6 bigint,day7 bigint)as
$BODY$
BEGIN
return query
with cte as(
select * from crosstab($$
select  follow_up_by,next_follow_up_date,count(*) from sales_enquiry_follow_up where next_follow_up_date between _from and _to
group by follow_up_by,next_follow_up_date 
order by follow_up_by,next_follow_up_date$$,$$select date::timestamp without time zone
from generate_series(
  _from,
  _to,
  '1 day'::interval
) date$$)
as(id integer, dd bigint,dd1 bigint,dd2 bigint,dd3 bigint,dd4 bigint,dd5 bigint,dd6 bigint)
)
select cte.id,u.username,cte.dd,cte.dd1,cte.dd2,cte.dd3,cte.dd4,cte.dd5,cte.dd6 from cte left join users u on cte.id=u.id;

END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```

I am getting this error `column "_from" does not exist`. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because argument of crosstab is just string you must include  arguments directly:

```
$$
select  follow_up_by,next_follow_up_date,count(*) from sales_enquiry_follow_up where next_follow_up_date between $$ || quote_literal(_from) || $$ and $$ || quote_literal(_to) || $$
group by follow_up_by,next_follow_up_date 
order by follow_up_by,next_follow_up_date$$
```