# Column "nameUser" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, function, common-table-expression

I am trying to create a function that accepts a parameter and returns a table. Inside the function, I am trying to transpose rows into columns using CTE. Here is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.statcountconparams(
    nameUser varchar)
    RETURNS TABLE("Date" date, "Waiting for input" integer, "Not Started" integer, "Profiling" integer, "Project Closed (Won)" integer, "Project Closed (Lost)" integer) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
begin
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT *
    FROM crosstab($$
        select format('SELECT date_trunc(''month'', "Date_Created") as "Date",  
              "status", 
              count(status)
        FROM public.project where "ownerName"::varchar = %L
             group by "status", "Date" 
             order by "Date" asc',nameUser);
      $$,
      $$ SELECT DISTINCT "status" FROM public.project; $$
    )
    AS ct(
      "Date" date,
      "Waiting for input" int, 
        "Not Started" int, 
        "Profiling" int, 
        "Project Closed (Won)" int, 
        "Project Closed (Lost)" int
    );
end
$BODY$;
```

When I execute the following query:

select * from public.statcountconparams('Elvis Shakya');

I get the following error:

column "nameuser" does not exist

I am not sure why it is considering the parameter name as a column.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but unfortunately, I have tried that as well. It would give me the same error. And after seeing that error, I thought I could use format but apparently no. Yeah, the casting can be removed as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pass parameters in crosstab query postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41995171/pass-parameters-in-crosstab-query-postgres). `where ownerName = $$ || quote_literal(nameUser) || $$`. [Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ss8Rh5fV).

Answer (score 0):

Just to tackle the problem without giving advice on other things, focus on your dollar quotes. You have the following dollar-quoted string:

```sql
$$
    SELECT format(
        'SELECT date_trunc(''month'', "Date_Created") as "Date", "status", COUNT(status)
        FROM public.project
        WHERE "ownerName"::varchar = %L
        GROUP BY "status", "Date" 
        ORDER BY "Date" asc',

        nameUser
    );
$$
```

Compare this to the string `'nameUser'`. This is just the literal and it is not replaced with the value of a variable that happpens to coexist with a name that is a substring of this literal.
So this dollar-quoted string never contained the value of the variable `nameUser`.

Instead, after the `format`, your `WHERE` clause says `"ownerName"::varchar = nameUser` without any access to the function's parameter. So the database assumes `nameUser` is a column, but it cannot find it. This is, where your error is coming from.